# reloadData from different class?

Tags: xcode, uitableview, ios4, reloaddata

I am trying to reload a tableView from a different class. After some NSLogs in the console, my data is being altered but not changed. Below is some code:

**SecondViewController.m**

```
RootViewController *test = [[RootViewController alloc] init];
// Set up database connection
NSString *myDB = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"flashpics.db"];
database = [[Sqlite alloc] init];
[database open:myDB];

[database executeNonQuery:@"INSERT INTO albums (id, name, connections) VALUES (?,?,'No Connections')", theID, theName];
[test.listOfItems addObject:theName];


RootViewController *controller = [[RootViewController alloc] init];
[controller.tableView reloadData];

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Can you please help me solve probably one of the easiest questions that exists?

Thanks,
Coulton

**EDIT#1:** NSLogs display the following. Could this do with anything?
    `__NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x5883000 of class UITableView autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking`

**EDIT #2:** Added more code to the SecondViewController.m

**Edit #3:** For some reason it's not working.

SecondViewController.m

```
RootViewController *controller = [[RootViewController alloc] init];
[RootViewController refreshTableView];
```

RootViewController.m

```
- (void) refreshTableView {
[self.tableView reloadData];
NSLog(@"Refreshing TableView - %@", listOfItems);
}
```

I Inserted 'neato' in the array. Then I called reloadTableView in the SecondViewController.m to RootViewController.m. I did get an output, but it didn't update the tableView. Below is the NSLog.

```
Refreshing TableView - (
"Default Album",
"Hello.",
"This is cool!",
hi,
neato
)
```

P.S. I don't get results, but I do get stuff I programmed it to say through a NSLog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initialize your RootViewController twice. Twice too many I imagine. You need to find a reference to your view controller and add the item to it's listOfItems. Then call `reloadData` on that controller's UITableView.

Comment: Now that you say it - it isn't. In what classes does it need to be initialized in? And how should it be? In my - init ?

Comment: I have left a bunch of code out, but It does get data to populate it (from a NSMutableArray). Can you please provide some simple sample code? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I can't go into too much detail because a lot of it will depend on what you want to render in a table, but I've included an example that I hope will get you started.

Comment: Thanks for the code. After putting it in Xcode I get tons and tons of errors.... What do you mean about the array with tableData? I have an array, do I need to change the name of it?

Comment: How do you call to do a action from a different class? All methods I have tried failed.

Comment: You must have a reference to the other class. Then you do [otherClass method];

Comment: Thanks for the response! You have no idea how frustrated with this and how long I have been staring at it. Please check out my EDIT #3. Hopefully this will be the last question. Thanks again! Coulton.

Answer (score 1):

the question is `why?` or `what do you really want to do?`

Your code doesn't make much sense, you are creating a new instance of RootViewController, and you are calling reloadData before the tableView has showed you some data. No need to reload before the tableview has data. But I think you want to reference the old instance instead of the new one you've just created

If this is what I think it is, a Navigation Based project where SecondView gets created in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, and then pushed to the navigationcontroller you should try to call `[self.tableView reloadData];` in `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` of the RootViewController

But I'm just guessing (although I'm pretty good at this) because your code makes no sense. No need to reload the tableview at this stage, because the tableview doesn't have any data.

Comment: I have left out a bunch of code, for easier reading. This is what happens: After a user adds a album, it will do this. I have added a new string to the array and the database that the tableView from a different class gets created from. I have ran NSLogs on it, and it did in fact add it. But when I run the reloadData to that specific tableView, it doesn't realod the data. In fact, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: it still makes not much sense to call reloadData in the same method where you create the viewController. When you pass the control to another view (where the user adds the album) you have already left this method. --- You should not leave out important code for the sake of easier reading. Makes it very hard to figure out what is going on.

Comment: The view with all the album already loads. Then a user clicks ADD ALBUM. After they add it and it talks with the server, it adds is then refreshes. After that, it should refresh then close. I am not user the `viewWillAppear` will get called when that happens.